# Amazon S3, how to duplicate a JSON file to another bucket that updates when the orginal is updated?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, etl

I have a few JSON files in my S3 bucket that I would like replicated to another bucket. Not just a one time copy but will mirror the changes of the original when an update occurs, similar to a multicast to two different buckets.

If I just right click and hit copy and paste it into a another bucket, will that do the trick?

Comment: A quick Google search yielded this - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/crr.html. Is that what you're after?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solutions to this question

1. Create a Lambda file which maps to the Object Created (All) event type. So whenever a new object is created or modified or copied, the Lambda will get triggered; where the event will contain reference to the object. Copy the object from bucket A to bucket B inside the Lambda which will achieve your requirement.
   However, this wouldn't work for delete functionality. For Delete, you might have to create another Lambda for Object Removed (All) event, and delete the S3 object from bucket B when the object gets deleted in Bucket A.  This is near realtime
2. Write a scheduler which runs every N minutes where it copies all the contents of the bucket from A to B- but not a good scalable solution. This is more of a batch solution

My 2 paisas, hope it helps